# Xcode Simulator is showing a blank screen for every size except plus sizes

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, landscape, iphone-6-plus

i was using the simulator just fine until i switched to iphone 5 it shows a blank screen and checked every other screen as well and it seems only iphone 6 plus and iphone 6s plus are showing what i actually have on storyboards im not sure having it on landscape changes anything its my first time using this orientation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that having the main storyboard in landscape may affect it.  To test my hypothesis, add some element to the storyboard with "any any" mode, run simulator, then delete what you added and do exactly the same in landscape mode.  To keep auto layout from skewing results make sure what you add is horizontally and vertically centered both times.